# VSCode ShowinputBox have a mandatory field? Either trap the escape and force data input or disable the ability to escape

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I make an input field mandatory in VSCode ShowInputBox?
I do not want the user to be able to escape out.  I know I can trap the response to be undefined which tells me that the user did in fact escape but I then want to reissue the ShowInputbox. That becomes really messy. It would be cleaner to remain in the ShowInputBox and not proceed till data is present. "validateInput" is not an option as it doesn't get called when escape is pressed.

Is there any means of either suppressing the Escape key or trapping it such that the user has to enter some data into the field.

Seems a simple request but I cannot find any means of accomplishing this.

Comment: No, how would the user be able to abort the command because he made a wrong key press

Comment: That is the point . It is a mandatory field that requires input and cannot just be ignored.  I want to trap the attempted escape.

Comment: so if I by accident activate your command I'm unable to quit, I if Escape an input box **I want to abort the command**